# \Subsectionname in header breaks after a while

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, subsection

I am writing my thesis using subfiles and have split it up into sections and subsection. Each subfile contains a section. I use a fancy header with subsection and section in the header alternating on odd and even pages. It properly display section throughout the thesis but the subsection breaks after page 32. I have around 8 subfiles. Here is my fancyhdr code

```
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thesubsection\ \Subsubsectionname}%left on even
\fancyhead[RO]{\thesection\ \Sectionname}%right on odd
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Page \thepage} %page number is right on even left on odd
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Any known issues with this? should it all be in one .tex file and no subfiles?
I suspect it might have something to do with figures.

thanks

Comment: please provide an example that peopel can run to debug the problem. also where is `\Subsubsectionname` defined? it is not a standard command.

Comment: what do you mean by "breaks" if you get an error show the exact error message from the log.

Comment: by breaks it just stops writing anything. Eg it should at the top left say: 3.4 results but it just says 3.4

Comment: it's more usual to use `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` to pick up text from the current heading, but you have provided no example nor shown how `\S...`  are defined, so it's impossible to guess the cause of your problem.

Comment: Defining the headers like that (with section/subsection numbers and names directly in them is bound to fail sooner or later. Read the fancyhdr documentation, especially section 15 The scoop on LATEX’s marks. As @DavidCarlisle says it is more usual to use the marks, but I want to say it stronger: that is the only reliable way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I have not made any commands so im guessing it is package that has the \subsection and \section. It was more if anybody knew of problems like having subfiles or simmilar.

Comment: you need to provide an example otherwise no one has any chance to answer this. Even the fragment that you show will generate errors on the first line as `\fancyhf` is not defined until you load `fancyhdr` (which you show being loaded on line 2) then you are asking why `\Subsubsectionname` does not have the expansion that you expect without giving any clue how it is defined.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum your solution worked thanks